# protobufjs load from string

Tags: node.js, protobufjs

I get a `.proto` definition as a string input, can I load it into a `Root` object straight from the string, for example the string might look like this

```js
let protoStr = `syntax = "proto3";

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
}`
```

And I want to be able to load it

```js
let searchRequest = protobuf.loadFromStr(protoStr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `protobuf.parse` see https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/master/examples/custom-get-set.js#L7-L12